# How to fix the following? fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdlib.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-code

I am trying to compile my project with googletest using cmake, and I keep getting the above error.

I have looked at similar problems, and attempted the solutions there, to no result (mainly because i am using visual studio code and not visual studio, so I dont know how to change/update the sdk version, which is the problem with others)

I have checked through the compilers I am using, the libraries that are in the include path, and even tried copying a version of include files I know work into the workspace folder directly, and updating the include path to an absolute one rather than relative. (secondary problem is that compilers I downloaded [gcc, g++, etc] are not being recognized as build kits, so I cant select it for compiling from the ide. Instead, I simply gave the absolute path for the compiler, seen below, but this didnt fix the issue or cause any new ones)

When looking at the line where the error is occurring, it shows "cannot open include file .... " but when I right-click and select go to definition, it shows the correct locations for the file being.

my c_cpp_properties.json file

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "compileCommands": 
"${workspaceFolder}/build/compile_commands.json"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

i have changed the compiler several times in attempt to fix this, originally it was visual studio community 2019 amd64.

I originally wrote this project in Linux, and now am moving it to windows. That is a possibility for the source of the issues, but I have done a clean install since then ( moved just the source and header files, re-installed googletest, and attempted to build, which is now where the error is occurring).

Full errors: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdlib.h': No such file or directory

Comment: Do you get the same if you include the C++ header `cstdlib` instead?

Comment: If i remove that header, then the next one simply gives me the same error (sstream.h, saying "cannot open include file corecrt.h, no such file or directory")

Comment: It is clear that your toolchain is not properly configured. Try to compile a trivial project first.

Comment: @Acorn I attempted to compile a helloworld project, and the same error arises, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905\include\crtdefs.h(10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'corecrt.h': No such file or directory. There is a difference though, this error shows that the include file is not in the compiler include folder, while my full project simply shows the include not working in the specifc header file. How can I configure my toolchain from here?

Comment: @Arik Then your problem is now clear :-) I would suggest you re-read the installation manual of whatever toolchain you are using (MinGW?) and possibly CMake to see why it is not working.

Comment: @Acorn Cmake and MinGW are working, I believe the error is in the visual studio code compilation process. The other compilers are not even recognized as build kits, but the recognized ones (from visual studio community) all cause this error.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your project compiles just fine if you invoke CMake directly, then?